# How to used a trained neural network using nnstart in matlab in python and ROS

Tags: python, matlab, neural-network, ros

I have trained a model of neural network using nnstart in matlab. I have trained turtlebot3 sensor data that I got from  ROS application (I run in gazebo and got the sensor data) to improved the sensor. Now I would like to used it again in gazebo to have a better accuracy of the sensor. How can I apply it again to the ROS application? Or can I have a link or a class that I can subscribe to learn this? Thank you in advance!